# Why my XSS attack's onerror method not firing?

Tags: xss

I have been able to inject an `onerror` event to the HTML.

In the image you can see `onerror` has been injected, but it never fires.

[image]

Comment: Does it work if you change the src to an invalid url?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Judging by how `alert(1);" onerror="alert(1);` in the `src` attribute value got underlined I can guess that this is what you injected and that it is parsed as a string (you did not break out of tag value quotes). So there is probably no `onerror` attribute either, only value of `alert(1);" onerror="alert(1);` for `data-mce-src` attribute. To make sure, inspect the source code your browser receives, not some formatted dom representation.